# Need to find element just before regex match element via python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

The input is exactly as below:

`"dinem-5554\tlee"`

I need to perform regex match to get the value before `\tlee`), that is, `dinem-5554`. This is what I've tried:

```
m = re.findall(r'(\tlee)',a)[0]
if m:
    print m
else:
    print "none"
```

Comment: try `re.findall("(.+?)\tlee",a)`

Comment: Define "the value before". What should get matched in the string `"dinem-5554 lee"`? "dinem-5554"? "5554"? "4"? The space character? Something else?

Comment: You can also try `(.*)\tlee` and refer to capture group `$1`

Comment: I always wonder what `?` means in regex.

Comment: it means "non-greedy" in the context of my comment. avoids matching \tlee, stops at first \tlee.

Comment: Thanks everyone, any suggestions from where I can learn this topic more

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a regex. Use the builtin [`split` method of `str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

```
my_string = "dinem-5554\tlee"
groups = my_string.split('\tlee', 1)

if len(groups) > 0:
    print groups[0]
else:
    print 'none'
```

Or if you mean to split at the tab character:

```
groups = my_string.split('\t', 1)
```

Note that the second argument determines the number of times to split. If `my_string` contained multiple tab characters, it would only be split at the first one.